# Objective C: How to resolve Leak in Code (results from Instrument)

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I ran the instruments for my app (which contains a UITableView) and got the following results

The cell will will call the method [UICustomButton SetButtonWithAnswer....] everytime the cell becomes visible

EDIT: Added more screenshots

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The issue is that I am not sure what exactly is causing the leak. i have released all my alloc inits in the code. Why is it still leaking?

Any advise on this will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I added the UICustom Buttons as follows

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //Add like button
    UICustomButton *likeButton = [[UICustomButton alloc]init];
    likeButton.tag = 7;

    //Add comment button
    UICustomButton *commentButton = [[UICustomButton alloc]init];
    commentButton.tag = 8;

    //Add answer too button
    UICustomButton *answerButton = [[UICustomButton alloc]init];
    answerButton.tag = 9;

    [self.contentView addSubview:likeButton];
    [self.contentView addSubview:commentButton];
    [self.contentView addSubview:answerButton];

    [likeButton release];
    [commentButton release];
    [answerButton release];
}


//Set like button
UICustomButton *thisLikeButton = (UICustomButton *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:7];
[thisLikeButton setButtonWithAnswer:self.answerForCell buttonType:@"like" navcon:self.navcon andFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN, totalCommentLabelHeight + CELL_SPACING*4, 45, CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
thisLikeButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"];


//Set comment button
UICustomButton *thisCommentButton = (UICustomButton *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:8];
 [thisCommentButton setButtonWithAnswer:self.answerForCell buttonType:@"comment" navcon:self.navcon andFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN + 45 + 5, totalCommentLabelHeight + CELL_SPACING*4, 80, CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
thisCommentButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chat.png"];

//Set answer button
UICustomButton *thisAnswerButton = (UICustomButton *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:9];    
[thisAnswerButton setButtonWithAnswer:self.answerForCell buttonType:@"join in" navcon:self.navcon andFrame:CGRectMake(1.5*CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN + 45 + 5 + 80 + 5, totalCommentLabelHeight + CELL_SPACING*4, 60, CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
thisAnswerButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beer-mug_white.png"];
```

Comment: are you calling `self.imageView=nil;` and `self.label=nil;` in `dealloc` (I presume the property is with retain)?

Comment: Given that every object is being considered a leak, you might be leaking the `UICustomButton` object.

Comment: @babbidi, do I need to also set self.imageview to be nil in dealloc method as well? I always thought that just doing a [imageview release] is sufficient?

Comment: @Deepak, @babbidi, I have updated the screenshots with more code. Hope this is clearer

Comment: How are you adding the `UICustomButton` instance to the cell?

Comment: @Deepak, I have updated my qn to include the way I added UICustomButton

Comment: @Deepak, I ran the instruments and it seems like the leaks stared from the point when I called ' setButtonWithAnswer:' method. Not sure why the leak since I have released all the alloc inits.

Comment: @Zhen - no, only call one of them (setting the property to nil will release it as well as long as the property is synthesized or implemented correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every alloc/init inside `setButton:…` needs to be rethought.  You do **not** want to recreate those views just to set the values.

```
if (self.imageView == nil) {
  UIImageView tempImageView = alloc/init …
  self.imageView = tempImageView;
  [tempImageView release];
}

self.imageView.image = self.image;
```

and the same for the label

Comment: this is great :) I think this is cause of the problem. I have removed the alloc inits inside set button and that seems to resolve the issue. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code right you want a single copy of your custom button for each of "like", "comment" and "join in"? Then I think that you are adding too many custom buttons: they are getting added if cell=nil. UITableView creates a cell for each visible row, so there will be as many copies of each of them as visible rows.

Did you actually check if the cells are reused properly? That is that there have been only as many created as visible rows?

Next what about getters of self: answerForCell, navcon and answer.likers: are there any opened retains?

Comment: Stanczak, thanks for your response. Can you advise what needs to be done for the custom button? Do I add them outside the loop of cell = nil?

Comment: I guess that you need them only once, so you should add them in a place that gets called only once (viewDidLoad) or guard with a bool variable that you would toggle after creating the buttons, in which case you can create them independently of the cell=nil condition.

Comment: Hi actually I need them to be created for every cell. I.e. Each cell will have a like, comment and join in button. So I guess I cannot put it in view didload. I am just not sure why my buttons seem to have increasing retain count when using the allocation tool. I seemed to have done all my releases for all alloc/inits.

Comment: I see, then you have to create them for every cell, but what looks funny is why [self.contentView addSubview: likeButton] and not [cell.contentView addSubview: likeButton]?

Comment: Oh I just copied and pasted code. The addsubview codes actually belong to a seperate UITableViewCell Subclass, hence the "[SELF.contentView addSubview...]. Sorry if that caused any confusion

Answer (score 1):

it may be further down, but I cannot see `tempLabel` being released. You really need to tell us what is leaking. You should be able to work out whether it is the ImageView, label, etc.

Comment: Yeah I did release tempLabel. The issue is I am not sure what exactly is leaking, I can only see the lines where instruments says it is. But I am not sure why those lines are considered leaks. I updated the initial qn with more details of the code